# very simple c# submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several ImageButtons on the top of my page, then I have a textbox and button in the middle.  If you type in the textbox then hit enter on the keyboard the browser follows the link of the first ImageButton instead of the submit button next to the textbox.  I have ran into this in the pase and had to put the imagebuttons on the bottom of the page for it to work correctly, that is not an ok fix in this case.  I tried setting UseSubmitBehavior="true" , but that does nothing.  I tried putting the textbox and button in a separate DIV and a separate panel, didn't work either

TOP of the page

```
      <div style="position:absolute; left: 70% ; top: 5%;">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgFB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/facebook_icon.jpg"  PostBackUrl="http://www.facebook.com/832586561" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLI" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/linkedin_logo.jpg" PostBackUrl="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/scott-selby/33/304/44a" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/careerbuilder_logo.jpg" PostBackUrl="http://www.careerbuilder.com" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCP" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/codeplex_logo.jpg" PostBackUrl="http://www.codeplex.com" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Middle of Page

```
    <div ID="formPanel" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:235px;">
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Button ID="btnChangeCity" runat="server" Text="Change City" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can we get source code please? Pretty please? Please include the place where the VS engine creates the button! (Should be a partial class somewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set the default button via `<form/>` attribute.

```
<form defaultbutton="btnChangeCity" id="form1" runat="server">
  ...
</form>
```

Or use [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) control to set default button.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnChangeCity">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnChangeCity" runat="server" Text="Change City" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: @avd I still think that having an OnClick method ("sub" for submit in asp.net) is better then having a default button, as you can have multiple of them in that case.

Comment: @Shingetsu The Panel control does the same as you've post.

Comment: @AVD I realize Panel is similar (or even almost identical) to form. My main problem is that you assign a DefaultButton. I would prefer having `OnClick="sub"` since that allows you to have multiple submit buttons.

Comment: What is UseSubmitBehavior then? I was thinking that it was what  OnClick="sub" does

Answer (score 0):

You surround your controls with `<div>` which is a good idea, but to have it run at all you also need `<form>`. In case you just didn't include it, the submit button also has to have `OnClick="sub"` attribute.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp).